Is support for &rsquo; or the ’ symbol being removed?
I noticed I&rsquo;d and don&rsquo;t on a lot of website I have visited over the past couple of days. I know that this is an html entity, similar to   or no-break space, and is used to indicate a right single quotation mark. But I see that, (even after testing on multiple devices extensively on BrowserStack), that its support is being removed?
If this is so, should I stop using this entity?
Websites that st:
[https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB845659364525306000]
[https://www.lunavi.com/blog/don-rsquo-t-leave-your-digital-keys-under-the-mat]
[https://www.climbing.com/skills/tech-tip-alpine-donrsquot-spit-in-the-wind/]
[https://www.crosswordsolver.org/clues/i/iamprsquom-so-utterly-fantastic-on-many-levels.459893]
[https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20190301-the-surprisingly-radical-politics-of-dr-seuss#:~:text=propaganda%2C%20argument%2C%20persuasion.%E2%80%9D-,I%26rsquo%3Bm,-subversive%20as%20hell]
Thanks

Are you sure about that? Usually, when I see something like that in a web page, I look at the source, and I invariably see something like I&amp;rsquo;m, suggesting that somebody was in WYSIWYG mode in a web page editor, and pasted the literal I&rsquo;m in that mode.

Also, entities like &rsquo; don't apply to the actual URL, such as your lunavi.com, climbing.com, or crosswordsolver.com links - these are just bad generation on the part of the respective site maintainers.

I routinely use &rsquo; - and other "smart quote" entities in my website, and have (a) never seen what you describe, nor (b) gotten reports from my target community - who have often flagged typos at me on the site.

@JeffZeitlin, what about the BBC?

That's still in the URL.

I'm sorry - there does appear to be a problem with that BBC page, and I'm not seeing why. I suspect that there's something about their (complex) CSS or the mode that they're delivering the page in, but it's not something I can trace immediately with Chrome's tools.

I'm also seeing that even on my own website, both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 pages are having their entities converted into the actual characters; I'll have to check and see whether this is in my master copy or whether it's being "pre-processed" somewhere along the line.

@JeffZeitlin, it seems to work on my website https://wonderweb.live/test

This is definitely not a browser issue; some older pages on my site do not have entities converted into their actual characters, but still render correctly. I would look to malformed HTML and/or CSS and/or javascript/ecmascript on the sites exhibiting the problem.
